# SSL in Tomcat with APR and CentOS 6 not working as expected

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm facing a problem setting up my Tomcat with apr native lib,
I have the following:

- **Tomcat**: 7.0.42
- **Java**: 1.7.0_40-b43
- **OS**: Centos 6.4 (2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.i686)
- **APR**: 1.3.9
- **Native lib**: 1.1.27
- **OpenSSL**: openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.i686

My `server.xml` looks like:

```
...
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
...
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
SSLCertificateFile="/tmp/monitoringPortalCert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile="/tmp/monitoringPortalKey.pem"
SSLPassword="hide"
/>
...
```

I compiled the native lib as follow:

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-ssl=yes --prefix=$CATALINA_HOME 
make && make install
```

The APR is loaded ok:

```
Oct 06, 2013 7:55:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.27 using APR version 1.3.9.
```

But I'm still having this error:

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize the SSLEngine.
org.apache.tomcat.jni.Error: 70023: This function has not been implemented on this  platform
```

./configure outcome

```
[root@localhost native]# ./configure --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-ssl=yes --    prefix=$CATALINA_HOME && make && make install
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
Tomcat Native Version: 1.1.27
checking for chosen layout... tcnative
checking for APR... yes
  setting CC to "gcc"
  setting CPP to "gcc -E"
checking for JDK location (please wait)... /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40 from environment
checking Java platform... checking Java platform...
checking for sablevm... NONE
  adding "-I/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/include" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES
checking os_type directory...  linux
  adding "-I/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/include/linux" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for OpenSSL library... using openssl from /usr/lib and /usr/include
checking OpenSSL library version... ok
checking for OpenSSL DSA support... yes
  setting TCNATIVE_LDFLAGS to "-lssl -lcrypto"
  adding "-DHAVE_OPENSSL" to CFLAGS
  setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to ""
  setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to " /usr/lib/libapr-1.la  -lpthread"
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating tcnative.pc
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing default commands
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-    src/jni/native'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `local-all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-    src/jni/native'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-   src/jni/native'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `local-all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-  src/jni/native'
/usr/lib/apr-1/build/mkdir.sh /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/include/apr-1 /usr/apache-   tomcat-7.0.42/lib/pkgconfig \
                 /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tcnative.pc /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/pkgconfig/tcnative-  1.pc
list=''; for i in $list; do \
            ( cd $i ; make DESTDIR= install ); \
    done
/bin/sh /usr/lib/apr-1/build/libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c -m 755     libtcnative-1.la /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27 /usr/apache-    tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27
libtool: install: (cd /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib && { ln -s -f libtcnative-  1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so.0 || { rm -f libtcnative-1.so.0 && ln -s libtcnative-   1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib && { ln -s -f libtcnative-   1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so || { rm -f libtcnative-1.so && ln -s libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27   libtcnative-1.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.lai /usr/apache-tomcat-  7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.a /usr/apache-tomcat-   7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: warning: remember to run `libtool --finish /usr/local/apr/lib'
```

make && make install outcome:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-   src/jni/native'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `local-all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-  src/jni/native'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-   src/jni/native'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `local-all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.27-   src/jni/native'
/usr/lib/apr-1/build/mkdir.sh /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/include/apr-1 /usr/apache-   tomcat-7.0.42/lib/pkgconfig \
                 /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tcnative.pc /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/pkgconfig/tcnative- 1.pc
list=''; for i in $list; do \
            ( cd $i ; make DESTDIR= install ); \
    done
/bin/sh /usr/lib/apr-1/build/libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c -m 755     libtcnative-1.la /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27 /usr/apache-  tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27
libtool: install: (cd /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib && { ln -s -f libtcnative-   1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so.0 || { rm -f libtcnative-1.so.0 && ln -s libtcnative-  1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib && { ln -s -f libtcnative-  1.so.0.1.27 libtcnative-1.so || { rm -f libtcnative-1.so && ln -s libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27    libtcnative-1.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.lai /usr/apache-tomcat-  7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.a /usr/apache-tomcat-  7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: warning: remember to run `libtool --finish /usr/local/apr/lib'
```

It seems everything is fine, but the error is not self-explanatory.

Can someone help to understand where my error is? What am I missing?

Comment: I have done the same way that you and it worked just fine. Did you remembered to install the openssl-devel package?
Another thing, did you tried to execute the $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/configtest.sh to test your configuration? Best regards, Adail

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I thought I'd toss an answer on it anyway.

The only problem I can see is using `--with-ssl=yes` when configuring the native libs.  I've always used `--with-ssl=/usr` when configuring them.